# Decorator with Arguments: Would this be a better way?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I just started learning decorators. I feel I understand how to modify a decorator to use arguments, however I don't see why the decorator in Python was implemented so that this modification is necessary.

[Edit: For clarity.]
For a decorator without arguments, the below are equivalent:

```
@decorate
def function(arg):
    pass

function = decorate(function)
```

So, for a decorator with arguments, why not let the below be equivalent?

```
@decorate(123)
def function(arg):
    pass

function = decorate(function, 123)
```

I find this more consistent, easier to read, and easier to code.

Below is how python decorators work followed by how I expected them to work. [Edit: I added the expected output as well.]:

```
OUTPUT:
function HELLA NESTED! Decorated with OMG!
function NOT AS NESTED! Decorated with NOT SO BAD!

def python_decorator(dec_arg):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        def decorated_func(func_arg):
            print(func.__name__, func(func_arg), "Decorated with", dec_arg)

        return decorated_func
    return actual_decorator

@python_decorator("OMG!")
def function(arg):
    return arg

function("HELLA NESTED!")

def my_expected_decorator(func, dec_arg):
    # I expected the `func` parameter to be like `self` in classes---it's 
    # always first and is given special meaning with decorators.
    def decorated_func(func_arg):
        print(func.__name__, func(func_arg), "Decorated with", dec_arg)

    return decorated_func

# @my_expected_decorator("NOT SO BAD!") # This is what I expected.
def function(arg):
    return arg
function = my_expected_decorator(function, "NOT SO BAD!")

function("NOT AS NESTED!")
```

I looked at [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#warningwarningwarning) and didn't see a reason why decorators were not implemented in the above way, but again I'm new to this idea. I feel the above change would make decorators easier and more consistent to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the current implementation was chosen is because it's *more* consistent. If it was implemented the way you suggested, python would have to handle decorators very differently depending on how they're used:

- If the decorator takes no additional arguments like `@python_decorator`, it can be called immediately with the function as the sole argument.
- If the decorator is called with arguments like `@python_decorator("OMG!")`, python has to store those arguments somewhere and then insert the function as the first argument.
- If the decorator is *called* without arguments like `@python_decorator()`, what should happen? Should this be equivalent to `@python_decorator`? But then why are there two different ways to use a decorator with no arguments? Maybe that syntax shouldn't be allowed?

As you can see, an implementation like this would add some inconsistencies. The chosen implementation on the other hand is really quite intuitive: The code after the `@` symbol can be thought of as an expression, and the result of that expression is used as the decorator:

- In the case of `@python_decorator`, `python_decorator` is an expression that simply returns an existing decorator function.
- In the case of `@python_decorator("OMG!")`, the expression `python_decorator("OMG!")` also returns a decorator function.

In this sense, the chosen implementation is much more consistent than the one you proposed.

This rationale is also explained in [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax):

> The rationale for having a function that returns a decorator is that
>   the part after the @ sign can be considered to be an expression
>   (though syntactically restricted to just a function), and whatever
>   that expression returns is called. See [declaration arguments [16]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-September/048874.html).

---

Regarding the suggestions voiced in the comments:

- **Banning the syntax `@python_decorator` syntax and enforcing `@python_decorator()` instead**

  The problem I see with this is that the parentheses serve no real purpose and only add clutter. The vast majority of decorators is applied without arguments. It's unreasonable to change the syntax for this just to be consistent with decorators that take arguments.
- **Explicitly passing the decorated function as the first argument**

  Again, this wouldn't add any semantic meaning. It's already obvious that the decorator will be called on the function that's defined directly below the `@python_decorator` line. Forcing to user the explicitly pass the function as the argument is bad because

  1. It's a source of errors. It doesn't really *add* anything to your code, but a simple typo can cause an error. If you want to rename a decorated function, you now have to rename it in *two* places instead of just one.
  2. *The decorated function doesn't even exist yet!* Since the function definition comes *after* the decorator, it's impossible to refer to the function by name *in* the decorator.
  3. The whole point of decorators was to simplify and improve the `func = decorator(func)` syntax that had to be used before decorators existed. Having to write `@decorator(func)` instead wouldn't really be a significant improvement, would it?

Comment: Also, we could do like we do with `__init__(self)` and write `@ decorate(func)`. Why is one explicit while the other is implicit? Requiring the `func` argument would then make decorators with arguments an easy and clear extension of decorators without arguments---just add more arguments.

Comment: RE: "If the decorator is called without arguments like @python_decorator(), what should happen?" I would argue `@python_decorator()` (or `@python_decorator(func)` if we want a more explicit implementation like with `__init__(self)`) would be the required syntax to call the decorator function. And there's precedent for this kind of implied meaning: `class Name(Object): vs class Name(): vs class Name:`

Comment: @JDG I've updated my answer to address your comments. About the comparison with the `self` parameter: That is completely different. The placement of the decorator already makes it obvious which function is being decorated. Forcing the user to repeat the function name in the decorator is just an annoyance and a source of errors. The `self` parameter on the other hand would be entirely implicit if it weren't explicitly listed in the function signature. It would be as if that parameter appeared out of nowhere.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying we write `@decorate(the_specific_function_name_written_below)`; the suggestion was `@decorate_this(func)`, `@decorate_some_other(func)`, `@decorate_yet_another(func)`---like how we always use `self` by convention regardless of whether I'm working in `ThisClass` or `ThatClass`. (And thanks for adding to your answer.)

Comment: Addressing your point 3, I believe a point of decorators---in addition to removing the `func = dec(func) repetition`---was to put that line at the func  declaration where it's most needed. As for retyping, I'll stress that I was suggesting a generalized `func` be used (like `self`) rather than naming the specific function below.

Comment: What I don't feel you've addressed, however, is say I agree with you that I don't want the extra `() or (func)`. So, make it implicit. You said there would be confusion between `@decorate and @decorate()`. Is there confusion about `class Animal: and class Animal():`? My impression is no. (And sorry for the fuss---perhaps I don't know enough about the implementation of all these things to fully understand your points.)

Comment: Also, there's somewhat similar implicitness with method calls: `obj.method() == class.method(obj)`.

Comment: @JDG You have to keep in mind that the 2nd half of my answer is just my own opinion. It's quite possible that we disagree on some points. But as far as I know, there is no information about this in the PEP. Those ideas may have been rejected for unknown reasons, or perhaps they weren't even taken into consideration at all. I don't know what the official stance on your suggestions is.

Comment: @Aran-Frey Thanks for clarifying that it's your opinion; there are people on here who do speak with first-hand knowledge of how the decisions were made! I'll try to approach PEP with it---you're probably right about the reasoning and I just don't know enough to see it---but maybe by submitting it, I can get a more clear answer as to why decorators are as they are.

Comment: Check out this implementation of a more consistent `decorator`: http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html